# Adding order through Android app Prestashop

Tags: android, prestashop

I'm developing an Android app for my prestashop. However, I cannot add orders: whenever I go to all orders in the BO, I don't find them, yet I find them in order detail by customer. I don't know where to insert my order.

Could you tell me what are the main order tables where I need to insert my order?

Comment: Did u read http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Web+service+tutorial ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link, I read carefully what was in the link but didn't find what i was looking for. Any further help please ?